# Ability score generator doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x

fond most of this "D&D random character generator" online at another source (cant remember where exactly, I will cite it when I find it again) and it all works save where it rolls and assigns the ability scores

```
#### Ability score generator
def __GetAbilityScores__(characterClass):
    scores = []
    for x in range(6):
        score = []
        for x in range(4):
            score.append(random.randint(1,6))
            score = sorted(score)
            score.pop(0)
            scores.append(sum(score))
    scores = sorted(scores)
    arrangedScores = {"STR":0, "DEX":0, "CON":0, "INT":0, "WIS":0, "CHA":0}
    match characterClass:
        case 'Fighter':
            arrangedScores["STR"] = scores[5]
            arrangedScores["CON"] = scores[4]
            arrangedScores["DEX"] = scores[3]
            arrangedScores["WIS"] = scores[2]
            arrangedScores["CHA"] = scores[1]
            arrangedScores["INT"] = scores[0]
        
        case 'Wizard':
            arrangedScores["INT"] = scores[5]
            arrangedScores["CON"] = scores[4]
            arrangedScores["DEX"] = scores[3]
            arrangedScores["WIS"] = scores[2]
            arrangedScores["CHA"] = scores[1]
            arrangedScores["STR"] = scores[0]

        case 'Rouge':
            arrangedScores["DEX"] = scores[5]
            arrangedScores["CON"] = scores[4]
            arrangedScores["CHA"] = scores[3]
            arrangedScores["STR"] = scores[2]
            arrangedScores["INT"] = scores[1]
            arrangedScores["WIS"] = scores[0]
    return arrangedScores

# chara info is stored here
class character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.race = race[random.randint(0,len(race)-1)]
        self.characterClass = job[random.randint(0,len(job)-1)]
        self.gender = gender[random.randint(0, len(gender)-1)]
        self.name = __GetRandomName__(self.race, self.gender)
        self.abilityScores = __GetAbilityScores__(self.characterClass)

newCharacter = character()

print(vars(newCharacter))
```

whenever i run this, everything else works but the ability scores come back as "0" across the board. Any help would be awesome. I'm just starting out with python and went looking for this as a project to help me learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fellow D&D enjoyer, hope your campaign goes well

Now your error lies here.

```py
for x in range(6):
    score = []
    for x in range(4):
        score.append(random.randint(1,6))
        score = sorted(score)
        score.pop(0)
        scores.append(sum(score))
```

**You are inserting into score list then removing the only element that the list has, therefore, sum is always equal to zero**.

I got that out of the for scope and fixed it for you.
Change that scope with this and it should work just fine !

```py
scores = []
for x in range(6):
    score = []
    for x in range(4):
        score.append(random.randint(1,6))

    # Sort items from lesser to greater and remove the first item 
    score = sorted(score)
    score.pop(0)

    # Just save the sum of it into score
    scores.append(sum(score))
```